# Errors while submitting data to the server using form

Tags: php, registration, subscriber

I am trying to submit data through form and came across the below error:

> Warning: `mysql_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ..

Please find the code I have tried.

```
//connection end to my data server.

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

     $user_name = $_POST['name'];
     $user_email = $_POST['email'];
     $user_skype = $_POST['skype'];

    if($user_name==""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your user name!')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    if($user_email==""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your email!')</script>";
        exit();
    }       

    if($user_skype==""){
        echo "<script>alert('please enter your skype id.')</script>";
        exit();
    }   

    $check_email = "select * from binary where user_email = '$user_email' ";

    $run = mysql_query($check_email);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    echo "<script>alert('Your email $user_email address already exist. please try another.')</script>";
    exit();

    }

    $query= "insert into binary (user_name, user_email, user_skype) values('$user_name','$user_email','$user_skype')";

    if(mysql_query($query)){
    echo "<script>window.open('success.html','_self')</script>";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Please explain me details i am new in php.. :(

Comment: For a start, consider moving away from the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and use something like MySQLi instead: it's far more secure. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1):

**binary** is `sql reserrve word`

use **backticks** around it

```
$check_email = "select * from `binary` where user_email = '$user_email' ";
```

check this link for sql reserve word. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

and learn **mysqli_** function or **P.D.O** as mysql is deprcitaeted

Answer (score 0):

Please update your query:
It should be

```
$check_email = "select * from `binary` where user_email = '".$user_email."' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems select query returns boolean false because

```
$check_email = "select * from binary where user_email = '$user_email' "
```

where `user_email = '$user_email'` can not parse value of `'$user_email'` because variable inside single quat does not parsed with their value

**use:-** where user_email = ".$user_email;
and everything should work